# Sending battery info attached with GSM through SMS

Tags: c, embedded, uart, gsm

I am writing a C code for receiving battery using GSM modem SIM 800E. I am using AtMega16 uC. Here I have used AT commands to get battery info.

```
void uart_send(unsigned char ch)     //Function to send via UART
{
    while(!(UCSRA &(1<<UDRE)));
    UDR=ch;
}

void bat()                         //Function to get battery info and send SMS via UART
{   
    int x;
    char battery[16];
    UCSRB &= ~(1<<UDRIE);
    writecommand("AT+CBC");        //AT command to get battery status(My program stuck here)
    for(int x = 0;x<20;x++)        //Reading 20 characters by the response of AT+CBS
    {
        while(!(UCSRA & (1<<RXC)));
        battery[x] = UDR;
    }

    UCSRB |= (1<<RXCIE);

    for(int x=1;x<20;x++)          //sending 20 characters to UART
    {
       uart_send(*battery);
    }
}

int main()
{

    DDRB=0xff;                     //PORT as output port for LCD
    uart_init();                   //initializing UART
    _delay_ms(1000);
    writecommand("AT");
    writecommand("AT+CMGF=1");      //setting GSM to Text Mode
    writecommand("AT+CNMI=2,0,2,0,0");

    while(1)
    {
        bat();
        transmit("AT+CMGS=\"+9195xxxxxxxx\"\r");  //Sending SMS with values in UART buffer
        _delay_ms(10);
        uart_send(26);    // command to send SMS
}
```

When I run the code it stuck in the bat() function (at"AT+CBC") it displays the battery info on the LCD and terminal both but doesn't send it by sms and program doesn't proceed further. Please suggest me ways to get the info through SMS.

**Edit**

Regarding comments by [Loongcat](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/49463/looongcat)

I am receiving 20 characters after the comman "AT+CBC" then it should receive that. this is the loop `for(int x = 0;x<20;x++)`

Comment: What type of GSM module do you use?

Comment: I am using SIM800E GSM module

Answer (score 2):

1) AT+CMGS must go before the body of sms (place bat() after transmit())

2) You're not detecting the end of answer to AT+CBC command, that's poor way. You must receive symbols until you've get "OK"

Comment: I am receiving 20 characters after the comman "AT+CBC" then it should receive that. this is the loop for(int x = 0;x<20;x++)

Comment: I think it will cause trouble if he send an `AT+CMGS` then an `AT+CBC`, the message sending may will be interrupted because of the new AT command.

Comment: @BenceKaulics you're right, missed that. He needs to get +CBC answer first, then start sms typing with +CMGS

Answer (score 2):

I see the following problems in your code:

1. In the `bat()` function you store the battery info in a local string (`char battery[16];`)

   - The size of this array is **16** but you are saving **20** characters (`for(int x = 0;x<20;x++)`) into it. If you are expecting **20** characters you should use an array with a size of **20 + 1**, plus one for the terminating null character: `\0`.
   - A local variable is allocated on the stack and is therefore unavailable once the function finishes execution. You may still be able to reach the stored value but there is no guarantee to that, because it will be marked as free memory space and some other function may overwrites.
   - Your `uart_send` function expects `unsigned char` as a parameter, so this call is wrong: `uart_send(*battery);` it should be `uart_send(battery[x]);`

In the current state of your program there won't be any problem since you transmit this string in the `bat()` function, but you should transmit it after the `AT+CMGS` command, where this string won't be available.

If you just call the `bat()` function after the `AT+CMGS`, it will cause problems, because the `AT+CBC` command will be sent to the module, which for it will answer. I think it will interrupt the execution of the `AT+CMGS` command.

So I suggest you to save the battery info first into a variable which won't lost, and the send it at the correct time. A correct message sending sequence should look something like this:

1. Get the battery info from the module and save it for later use.
2. Send the `AT+CMGS="+9195xxxxxxxx"` command.
3. Wait for the module to respond with: `>`, this means that the module has processed the phone number and now ready to receive the SMS body, [battery info].
4. When you received the `>` character, you can send the battery info to the module.
5. Now, send the message using the `<CTRL>-<Z>` character, `0x26` in ASCII.
6. On successful delivery the module will return a message ID like: `+CMGS: 62`

Comment: or *(battery+x), same things

Comment: Indeed, that one works too.